# How to create boolean list of boolean depended on inserted count and list in f#

Tags: list, f#, count, boolean

I need code which creates boolean list depended on inserted list and count. For example, when the user gives **List[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]** and **count=2** then then code makes **bool List [true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true,false,true]**

When **count = 3** then it will make **bool List [true, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, false]**

If **count = 4** then **[true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false]**  and so on....

I´ve written following code but i think, that this code is wrong, i am new to f# so i need you help. Thanks.

```
   let Group (s1 : List) (c : int) =
        let lenght = List.length(s1)
        (lenght)
           let rec MakeBool (count : int) (boolist : List) =
                while lenght > 0 do
                    if lenght % count = 0 then boolist = true::boolist 
                    if lenght % count <> 0 then boolist = false::boolist    
                    lenght = lenght - 1
                    MakeBool count boolist
```

Comment: It might be worth expanding your question to say *why* you are wanting to do this. You've got some valid answers, but by giving a bit of context you may get some suggestions for avoiding this (rather odd) construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using high-order function (recommended):

```
let group ls c = 
    ls |> List.mapi (fun i _ -> i%c = 0)
```

Rolling your own function:

```
let group ls c =
 let length = List.length ls    
 let rec makeBool count acc =
  if count = length then acc // Come to the end of ls, return the accummulator
  elif count%c=0 then // Satisfy the condition, prepend true to the accummulator
    makeBool (count+1) (true::acc)
  else  // Otherwise prepend false to the accummulator
    makeBool (count+1) (false::acc)
 List.rev (makeBool 0 []) // The accummulator is in backward order, reverse it
```

Comment: Note: your solutions suppose that he wants to modulate on the index in the list, and not on the value. Given his example list, that *could* be what he wants, but I thought it was worth pointing out, before he gets marked down... :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
let Group l c =  [ for l' in  0..l  -> (l' % c) = 0 ]
```

The signatue is `Group : int -> int -> bool list`

- [ a..b ] creates a List of integers from a to b (both inclusive)
- [ for x in a..b -> f (x) ] does the same, but applies f to each element.
- (a % c) = 0 just checks if a is modulus c.

//H

Comment: Both solutions are great, thank you for your feedback guys :-)